# Simple logarithmic equation$ (\log 2^x = 180)$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-distribution

I've been trying to wrap my head around a simple logarithmic equation.

So, there are many ways to represent it:

- $10^{180} = 2^x$
- $\log(2^x) = 180$
- $5^{180} = 2^{(x-180)}$

(If you could not use Napierian logarithm while resolving - or at least explain it when used - I would be thankful)

Comment: MathJax tip: You have to put curly brackets around an exponent if it is longer than one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that for injectivity

$$10^{180}=2^x$$

$$\log \left(10^{180}\right)=\log (2^x) $$

$$180 \log 10 =x\log 2$$

$$x=\frac{180 \log 10}{\log 2}$$

that is

- in base $10 \implies x=\frac{180 }{\log 2}$
- in base $2 \implies x= 180 \log 10$

Comment: that is misinterpreted, my case is **10^180 = 2^x** , not   **10^180 = x^2**

you inverted the exponent and the base

Comment: @Tonio I was referring to the title. Please check that in order to clarify what the OP is about.

Comment: so that`s my bad then, welp

Comment: well done finally! bye

Answer (score 2):

$$\log x^2=180$$
$$10^{\log x^2}=10^{180}$$
$$ x^2=10^{180}$$
Thus $$ x=\pm 10^{90}$$

Comment: **log 2^x = 180** is different from **log x^2 = 180**

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

- **10^180 = 2^x**
- **log 10^180 = log 2^x**
- **180(log 10) = x(log 2)**
- **180*1 = x(log 2)**
- **x = 180/log 2**
- **x = 597.94705708**